# ItoProcess with WhiteNoiseProcess

Tags: differential-equations, random, finite-difference-method, random-process

Is there a way to use `ItoProcess` with a white noise process, instead of the usual `WienerProcess`? If I just naively use `WhiteNoiseProcess` I get the error

> WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0,1]]] is not a random process recognized by the system

Here's a minimal example:

```
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + Sqrt[1 + x[t]^2] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, w \[Distributed] WhiteNoiseProcess[]];
RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}];
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use WhiteNoiseProcess inside the equation directly. You should integrate w.r.t a brownian motion WienerProcess and where you have the white noise, express it as a the derivative of the WienerProcess instead.

Comment: Ok maybe I don't really understand the `ItoProcess`. Honestly I just wanted an easy way to simulate differential equations with a noise term that adds a random number in a certain range each time step, and this seemed to more or less do the job.

Comment: `\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
  Sqrt[1 + x[t]^2] \[DifferentialD]w[
     t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]` should work because dw/dt _is_ the white noise.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the explanation